# Why is creating tag synonyms a moderation privilege?

Tags: discussion, privileges, privilege-types

[New tag creation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) is a **creation privilege**.

[Tag synonym suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) is a **moderation privilege**.

Why? They appear to be the same kind. Is it just because creation of a tag synonym automatically generates a vote to allow the new synonym?

After all, [wiki editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) is a creation privilege as well.

Comment: tag creation, you create a tag, wiki editing you write (create) the wiki. Tag synonym what are you creating? The link maybe, but what you're really doing is organising existing content i.e. moderating.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well a tag synonym is a word creation. Exactly as a tag creation is. Tag creation doesn't obviously implies that you will fill the description, this is *wiki edit* privilege. So both create the same amount of data.

Comment: Tag synonyms are arguably a much more delicate matter. I've seen plenty of synonym requests here on Meta that turned out to be bad ideas. They require some experience with the system, and with the tags in question.

Comment: Tag synonym creation is not word creation.  You take an existing tag and get it to mean something else.  Lots of mayhem and confusion if that was not an appropriate change and the tag was already commonly used.  It is not commonly used when you create a new tag.

Comment: The [suggest-tag page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)  does not contain a link how someone can start the process to remove a tag synonym. How do i suggest to remove a synonym? See my attempt here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14152650

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag creation and wiki editing fall under content creation.

Tag synonym operations are maintenance operations. You may be "creating" or at least proposing a new tag, but that "tag" serves no other purpose than to redirect to an already-existing tag. There's not a whole lot of actual content creation going on. Plus, you generally don't propose a tag synonym unless it is absolutely necessary.

Similarly, when you flag a post, you may be creating a flag but you're not really creating any content — if anything, you're creating a maintenance task and delegating it to others with the necessary privileges.